# Style definition (style="display: block;") on HTML is affecting rails validation.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails form in a Bootstrap Tabbed Form crafted into position and functionality with JQuery. When Rails validates on the second partial form, it doesn't return to the second form of the tabbed form, so I tend to click on the tab before I could have access to what rails is validating.

**TabbedForm (app/views/clients/registrations/new.html.erb)**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1 class="#">
        <span class="">Create a Free Client Account</span>
      </h1>
      <p class="hidden-xs">
        Looking for work?
        <br class="visible-xs">
        <a href="/signup/contractor">Sign up as a freelancer</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%=  render 'shared/two_breaks' %>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <!--col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-3-->
      <div class="panel panel-login">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 tabs">
              <a href="#company-form" class="active" id="company-form-link"><div class="company">COMPANY</div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 tabs">
              <a href="#individual-form" id="individual-form-link"><div class="individual">INDIVIDUAL</div></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div id="company-form" role="form" style="display: block;">
                <h2>COMPANY</h2>
                <%= render 'companies/form', company: @company %>
              </div>
              <div id="individual-form" role="form" style="display: none;">
                <h2>INDIVIDUAL</h2>
                <%= render 'individuals/form', individual: @individual %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery powering the form**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets


$(function() {
    $('#company-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#company-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#individual-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#individual-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#individual-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#individual-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#company-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#company-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I believe the problem is because I did set a style on the form with the first form holding `display: block;` and the second form having `display: none;`

**Fix**
Tried fixing it but having this JQuery take position if the div has error. However, it didnt work

```
$(function() {
    $('#individual-form .div_with_errors:first').tab('show')
});
```

How can I make sure the second form having a style `display: none;` be the first to renders upon validation errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually is with the jQuery. There is no full definition of what will make the tab with error being the first to show.

I had to look into the `class of error definition in my source code` and used it to redefine my jQuery such that the tab with error is the one to be the first to show.

At the long run, here is the jQuery that fixed it:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets


$(function() {
    $('#company-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#company-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#individual-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#individual-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();

    });
    $('#individual-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#individual-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#company-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#company-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});


/*
* Thanks to (c) Ikechi Michael
* contact: +234808-385-0091
* */

$(function() {
    //first hide them both
    $('#company-form').fadeOut(100);
    $('#company-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $('#individual-form').fadeOut(100);
    $('#individual-form-link').removeClass('active'); 

    if ($('#company-form').find('.help-block').length > 0) { //class of error definition in my source code which is .help-block
        $('#company-form-link').addClass('active');
        $("#company-form").fadeIn(100);
    } //make company-form active if it has errors
    else if ($('#individual-form').find('.help-block').length > 0) { //class of error definition in my source code which is .help-block
        $('#individual-form-link').addClass('active');
        $('#individual-form').fadeIn(100);
    } //make individual-form active if it has errors
    else {
        $('#company-form-link').addClass('active');
        $('#company-form').fadeIn(100);
    } //if none have errors, show company-form by default
});
```